# Python: Format string with float, right alignment

Tags: python

I want to align a combination of str and float to the right side. In my example, "Tax = $" is a string and tax is a float. I have two ways to accomplish this.

```
print(("Tax = $%.2f" % tax).rjust(70))
print("%66s%.2f" % ("Tax = $",tax))
```

The output is the following:

```
                                                       Tax = $0.42
```

Both of them are working. But I don't think they are good enough. The codes are kind of burdensome. At the beginning, I wrote something like

```
print("Tax = $%.2f" % tax)
```

I tried to put a right align flag in this line, but I don't know where should I put it in.

Is there a neat way to do this?

Thank you,

Comment: No, there isn't. At least, not by your criteria.

Comment: you can also use like `'{:>66}'.format('$0.42')`

Comment: *The codes are kind of burdensome* - you are allowed to create a function with a descriptive name and use that to do the formatting with one of the ways you've listed you know? :)

Answer (score 0):

Now with f-strings available in python 3.6 and newer, here is another way to look at it:

`print(f"{(f'Tax = ${tax:.2f}'):>70}")`

Using temporary variables:

```
rightSideStuff = f'Tax = ${tax:.2f}'
print(f"{rightSideStuff:>70}")
```

The resource I used for finding how to align right:
https://medium.com/@NirantK/best-of-python3-6-f-strings-41f9154983e